# Javascript legacy nightmare - Trying to get my head around some compressed javscript

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, ecmascript-6, queue

Random one guys but I have has the misfortune of picking up and old legacy project for our systems queuing process and right now I am trying to piece together all the parts of it with no documentation - yes I said it NO DOCUMENTATION!

The one part I am really struggling with is this very ugly piece of javascript - I can see it's in an interval that keeps submitting a form in an interval every 400ms but it's all the insanity in the middle i am trying to work out.

```
(function(){
var a = function() {try{return !!window.addEventListener} catch(e) {return !1} },
b = function(b, c) {a() ? document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", b, c) : document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", b)};
b(function(){
  var a = document.getElementById('cf-content');a.style.display = 'block';
  setTimeout(function(){
    var s,t,o,p,b,r,e,a,k,i,n,g,f, OBQXEnQ={"GMuEaNBC":+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))};
    g = String.fromCharCode;
    o = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
    e = function(s) {
      s += "==".slice(2 - (s.length & 3));
      var bm, r = "", r1, r2, i = 0;
      for (; i < s.length;) {
          bm = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 18 | o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 12
                  | (r1 = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++))) << 6 | (r2 = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)));
          r += r1 === 64 ? g(bm >> 16 & 255)
                  : r2 === 64 ? g(bm >> 16 & 255, bm >> 8 & 255)
                  : g(bm >> 16 & 255, bm >> 8 & 255, bm & 255);
      }
      return r;
    };
    t = document.createElement('div');
    t.innerHTML="<a href='/'>x</a>";
    t = t.firstChild.href;r = t.match(/https?:\/\//)[0];
    t = t.substr(r.length); t = t.substr(0,t.length-1); 
    a = document.getElementById('jschl-answer');
    f = document.getElementById('challenge-form');
    ;OBQXEnQ.GMuEaNBC+=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]));OBQXEnQ.GMuEaNBC-=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))/+((+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]));OBQXEnQ.GMuEa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nQ.GMuEaNBC+=+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))/+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]));a.value = (+OBQXEnQ.GMuEaNBC + t.length).toFixed(10); '; 121'
    f.action += location.hash;
    f.submit();
  }, 4000);
}, false);
})();
```

Here is the markup

```
  <form id="challenge-form" action="/Queue.aspx?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=5f04d92efb1edb011edabc24cda3a235e06eb8ba-1581158560-0-AW-KwafTO7e0NxbCGPpzLlWrAU7w5hIso3jE7mgZFhCOvFb1g3xqglnwGhj6WL-2y_ECUZbobHbvPBykf59dve4xLS5aozksjkZkH12e8LOF1svbylQRNURkKmiILeAOhzeKXmzSH4ipu1OhgrKsjNfLgvcXIWz4a24GCSxxjNZKnLmsKLI3pPcN6SxeZASqynHvvZVf1n6Xa297FqIEu2a44P0_ztTkpIJodgatQyaXHrI4zYudSNdD_OGEmgCpyhuyHLjx8un4ILE2lcKwecKmWx2UZlzttaeQgsqJP3vd" method="POST" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="r" value="10a1cf729542cb5335935dbd86df47dfd6e6c413-1581158560-0-AbUplhHDvPuYV2B2BYVsWPZBU73o1fTlVXNJ/9uyPNG3D37ODbaeVdeHe5X51WlC6rAwkqXWDPrLJUyVCBDMU+rvLP38yZycbr3c95pZiUAa1NGWDB8ebbDB2Rcyanw5UKxYCgSCMGtxNlypoWJprK4p2RNjI5fG/9r+7nY7es28+MQC2morY38wCjTpKbY0SREp2iCToPB0uq8nlQwkHTK8jjuNYK4ZK+zYKVffgT+U6s62z8sglX1YA83iSzCWgM3piWdTvtz6TKddEuHMmY6RsOcaog8DuuO5+RqT0Re9qaGUO9x/pCf6N4ho5Ms1byBnPYtzD1gnnlfKjtD29FEGcsz1U1x4aRe8D6SqvzTb/IEudytoLLWpL4Q9oSKv4t8DdwZs6I5w5LMBcltUOjm69ptN+qFg/m+0hzFzHXAOaLcu1UZU725QQofIPQw21ofFsDihHXYHiuSEZq1jZMAcOKtaq8pY4fyzxyccV6qvfz4p1U3RuWnplKt6OP33dquly4DlJOamOuAnrPz3oWOQLJ5tDz95mg8GdbzvX088pe1nh9dp1YTDup82zIv3Gebme2/pzPCKjcCxBOOJHEK1H0i5qZoNi6WROohbvPc0kGwxyJWsGD1sXY2QpAfw0Mt2IXujShOOtD94JY4Yc7cLx4H4YPbqKh+ouwf9FRWH6dWTz6hnIMmNtbduNrgDxfl0rlWSyyeIOzty9HXg4+K9mvw4E5irwxdXJ2mDfHsqbbiGvGlwkcq1bAioSGYh3sL3fqenRkVEdJIGKE29wg93v7ZgeD+lIaFmF6Zy0nv1MSY8KVkZrERoFSGlJJgbTG3rkHagIKa72rs4h0d07wkJNIqkKwrJtS8txO+KVpyalCbVrqhb1yocmaFysoV5P1IFPTNrzocZelCkqMMq4Mquxq0TpIwEWvxfMN6JwXuM+7hrp7rD7hJzCDqJUiitA3TIUybw6FSie/Bwdq3fPHhnwg8dpVn372hcK/l9UPcyR+b+TReMy6HxO+/qPiNiYpQ/vuYjTs5efIeJ4hULJl2JRNV6LkPAf2Ees4KvBBVp2FjBubxjYmfORygZIjCQUCP2WcgXD34zy4w8kwngxsKiQ8UhHsiehvAl//5J1tA5H6Me9RuReJ8kWmelnFP+mrV4RnMpjmFifmRY9pwYQb1AIkl7VGsi5eR6Vmeq2Bb/iRhyFxIIpxzHJV9GF/rrO37/vjlTFxNUQ72CTS38jtUBaQivCFx2+qb/kfI5nW4DP3LOTUz9D/zJGmWYHKkz3G2jX/UWDWm2CzbtfsLLfzercuWl3hPqkdwqg/QZz9G05Qayf+jKCC+mWYuSNL8MHXxZereb6jPMyAu8n9jtVjXAxgtGGZMuIqXK+HOCMMMfQL4zxuUBe4Z6lJ45XiL0Hn0fX9JPY5ahi0zzX7ZSLSL3E2iiDcHbFxvByBYNNh1uTaxKoJyxVCrYZFBbpUkriI01N5u//u3nc5RYcgTsbsuC/31cDqmTO0KNkbN0/BYN9gG0qP4q2Hf0CaIGgw/Ip7QwzmF491opP8iIysH8kEp4rMSjeL6XIVLjhGN9dXfWcklq9G9A0iaIj2b2O1ra0y6nCauN+8DTWPRbz4pmDUryfDkG35/kk8wzqG5Yp5+TTeX9+4MJGMm5wz5fa3K8vi7sn4wdneroVB2TIb6evQZ//eSWFgEw67MFOW86+ROj"></input>
<input type="hidden" name="jschl_vc" value="d308f58453fdc399f02de1819459f64d"/>
<input type="hidden" name="pass" value="1581158564.634-jWe4nK3hOC"/>
<input type="hidden" id="jschl-answer" name="jschl_answer"/>
```

Comment: I hope you were given good money for this

Comment: Start with renaming variables. `a` is `eventListenerAvailable`, `b` is `onLoad` and so on ...

Comment: `var  s,t,o,p,b,r,e,a,k,i,n,g`, this seems intentional :)

Comment: Can you point to the webpage URL where this script runs?

Comment: @ShanevandenBogaard some obfuscators / minifiers let you set up your preferred isograms. And this sure looks like the work of some obfuscator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's see how we can make sense of this code, topic by topic.

### The bracket-obfuscated expressions.

These could potentially call functions, so let's see exactly what they do. They always appear as numerator or denominator in a single division. So I list here all the used numerator/denominators:

```
+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))
+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))
+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![]))
+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))
+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))
+((+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))
+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))
+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))
+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]))
+((!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(+[])+(+[])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![]+!![])+(!+[]+!![]+!![]+!![]))
```

These expressions work with only a few different components:

```
!![]
!+[]
(+[])
[]
```

`!![]` and `!+[]` evaluate to `true`, and as they all appear as operand of an addition or unary plus, they are coerced to `1`. Replacing that, gives:

```
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+[])+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(+[])+(+[])+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+[])+(+[])+(1+1+1+1)+(+[])+(1+1+1+1)+(+[])+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(+[])+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+[])+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(+[])+(1+1+1+1)+(+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+[])+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1)+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+[])+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(+[])+(1+1+1+1)+(+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((+1+[])+(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(+1)+(+[])+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+[])+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(+[])+(1+1+1+1)+(+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+[])+(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+[])+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(+[])+(+[])+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+[])+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(+[])+(+[])+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1))
```

The `(+[])` components evaluate to 0, and the remaining `+[]` trigger a string concatenation, so that corresponds to `+""`. The result:

```
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+"")+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+0+0+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+"")+0+(1+1+1+1)+0+(1+1+1+1)+0+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+0+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+"")+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+0+(1+1+1+1)+(+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+"")+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1)+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+"")+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+0+(1+1+1+1)+(+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((+1+"")+(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(+1)+0+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+"")+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+0+(1+1+1+1)+(+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+"")+(1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+1+1+1+"")+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+0+0+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1))
+((1+1+1+1+"")+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1+1+1)+0+0+(1+1+1+1+1+1+1)+(1+1+1+1))
```

We can now calculate replace those 1+1+...+1 by what they evaluate to (don't deal with parentheses yet):

```
+((7+"")+(9)+(7)+0+0+(3)+(4)+(3)+(7))
+((9+"")+0+(4)+0+(4)+0+(6)+0+(9))
+((8+"")+(3)+(8)+0+(4)+(+1)+(6)+(4)+(+1))
+((9+"")+(4)+(2)+(3)+(8)+(7)+(5)+(2)+(8))
+((8+"")+(3)+(8)+0+(4)+(+1)+(6)+(4)+(7))
+((+1+"")+(2)+(7)+(+1)+(9)+(+1)+0+(9)+(9))
+((8+"")+(3)+(8)+0+(4)+(+1)+(6)+(4)+(7))
+((6+"")+(2)+(6)+(7)+(8)+(6)+(7)+(8)+(5))
+((7+"")+(9)+(7)+0+0+(3)+(4)+(3)+(7))
+((4+"")+(4)+(4)+(6)+(6)+0+0+(7)+(4))
```

The remaining, inner unary plus operators, in `(+1`, can be removed and all except the outer parentheses can be removed as well:

```
+(7+""+9+7+0+0+3+4+3+7)
+(9+""+0+4+0+4+0+6+0+9)
+(8+""+3+8+0+4+1+6+4+1)
+(9+""+4+2+3+8+7+5+2+8)
+(8+""+3+8+0+4+1+6+4+7)
+(1+""+2+7+1+9+1+0+9+9)
+(8+""+3+8+0+4+1+6+4+7)
+(6+""+2+6+7+8+6+7+8+5)
+(7+""+9+7+0+0+3+4+3+7)
+(4+""+4+4+6+6+0+0+7+4)
```

All the inner plus operators are now string concatenations, so this evaluates to:

```
+("797003437")
+("904040609")
+("838041641")
+("942387528")
+("838041647")
+("127191099")
+("838041647")
+("626786785")
+("797003437")
+("444660074")
```

The remaining unary operator performs the final evaluation:

```
797003437
904040609
838041641
942387528
838041647
127191099
838041647
626786785
797003437
444660074
```

You could have evaluated the expressions as they were in the dev console, but this way you are absolutely sure there are no hidden side effects or dependencies that could go unnoticed.

### The value of `OBQXEnQ.GMuEaNBC`

With the above expressions reduced to their numerical values, we get this:

```
var OBQXEnQ = {
    "GMuEaNBC": 797003437 / 904040609;
};
OBQXEnQ.GMuEaNBC += 838041641 / 942387528;
OBQXEnQ.GMuEaNBC -= 838041647 / 127191099;
OBQXEnQ.GMuEaNBC += 838041647 / 626786785;
OBQXEnQ.GMuEaNBC += 797003437 / 444660074;
```

... so that can be simplified to:

```
var OBQXEnQ.GMuEaNBC = 797003437 / 904040609 + 838041641 / 942387528 - 838041647 / 127191099 + 838041647 / 626786785 + 797003437 / 444660074;
```

... which is:

```
var OBQXEnQ.GMuEaNBC = -1.6885301087751048;
```

### The variables `s,t,o,p,b,r,e,a,k,i,n,g`

We ignore the hint :-)

Now that we have decoded the obfuscated expressions, it becomes clear that `e` is never called. So we can remove that function from the code.

The variables `o` and `g` were only used in `e`, so they can also be removed from the code.

Of the variables `s,t,o,p,b,r,e,a,k,i,n,g`, we only need to keep (for the moment) `t`, `r`, and `a`. The others are not used.

The loose expression `'; 121'` plays no role either.

### The value of `t.length`

There is this part in the code:

```
t = document.createElement('div');
t.innerHTML="<a href='/'>x</a>";
t = t.firstChild.href;
r = t.match(/https?:\/\//)[0];
t = t.substr(r.length); 
t = t.substr(0,t.length-1);
```

It is a complicated way to do `t = location.host`. The only use of `t` is its `length` in a later expression.

So `t.length` becomes `location.host.length`.  But it is clear that it depends on where this javascript is running. In comments below you mention the web address of this page, and so `t` evaluates to "queue-tickets.liverpoolfc.com", and thus `t.length` is 29.

With this simplication we no longer need variables `t` and `r`.

### The value assigned to `a.value`

We have reduced the assignment to `a.value` to:

```
a.value = (-1.6885301087751048 + location.host.length).toFixed(10);
```

As stated before `location.host.length` is 29 in your case. Therefore the above is equivalent to:

```
a.value = "27.3114698912";
```

### functions for listening to the `DOMContentLoaded` event

The two functions `a` and `b` are intended to execute code when the document is loaded, with backwards compatibility for pre-IE9.

The parameter variable `c` is getting value `false` in the actual call of `b`, but that is the default for `addEventListener`; we can omit that.

So ignoring the IE8 compatibility concern, the call of `b` is equivalent to:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
```

So we can skip the definition of those two functions as well. And since those were the only variables defined directly in the outer IIFE scope, we can leave that IIFE out as well.

### The result:

The above reductions lead to this code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById('cf-content').style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById('jschl-answer').value = "27.3114698912";
        var f = document.getElementById('challenge-form');
        f.action += location.hash;
        f.submit();
    }, 4000);
});
```

### Client / Server

This client code submits the form to the server page `Queue.aspx`. It passes information via the URL and via a POST payload.

The URL has two bits of information:

- `__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=`: a hardcoded value
- `#`: a so-called "hash", which is just a repetition of whatever was in the current URL's hash (following the `#` symbol).

The POST payload has this:

- `r=`: a hardcoded value
- `jschl_vc=`: a hardcoded value
- `pass=`: a hardcoded value
- `jschl-answer=`: the value which the JavaScript code provides, i.e. "27.3114698912" when run on your live site.

This HTTP-request is submitted to `Queue.aspx`, 4 seconds after the current page had loaded.

As your question provides no information on what `Queue.aspx` does with that information, my analysis ends here.

If you have control over `Queue.aspx`, then all this analysis is really irrelevant, as you could simply put some logging in the ASP (.NET) code of `Queue.aspx` and see:

- what exactly is in the POST variable `jschl-answer` which the client submits, and
- what is sent back to the client: which URL redirection (if any) and which content.

### Addendum

When trying the live URL myself, I note that it writes a cookie, so that the next time you visit that same URL, the redirection is immediate.

The first delay of 4 seconds (with `setTimeout`) seems to only serve as a protection against bulk attacks on the web site (DOS attacks). This is however a very simple measure and can be easily bypassed.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer man very interesting indeed - i have access to the aspx page but i am not a .NET dev and he is away at the moment hense why i reached out here - the live URL is https://queue-tickets.liverpoolfc.com/Queue.aspx

Comment: Updated my answer with the info about the live URL. Without information about the aspx page, this is where the analysis ends. I am not sure how we can help you more.

Comment: how can people bypass it?

Comment: @Johnwilliams the 4 second delay that trincot indicates as a probable protection against bulk attacks on the web site (DoS attacks) can be bypassed by a savvy user simply by opening up the browser debugger, and dumping in new code to hammer away at the server with numerous form submissions.  Typically protection against a DoS attack is handled by a network level device rather than relying on well behaved client software...

Comment: So can people openly bypass the queue all together here - or will that depend on what's happening on the server?

Comment: They can bypass the queue by using technology that will mimic the post-request exactly as it happens in the js-code, but without the 4 second delay. Using a tool like greasemonkey comes to mind. Of course, you don't know what the server side has implemented as logic, so no comment on that.

Comment: I just understand how removing the timeout and auto submitting bypasses the queue.

Comment: Sorry, i meant i don't haha - long day :(

Comment: Well, they might not bypass the *queue* (I don't know how that is implemented on the server), but they bypass the delay of 4 seconds, which would allow for a DoS attack to still have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const g = String.fromCharCode;
const o = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
const e = function(s) {
    s += "==".slice(2 - (s.length & 3));
    var bm, r = "", r1, r2, i = 0;
    for (; i < s.length;) {
        bm = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 18 | o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 12
                | (r1 = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++))) << 6 | (r2 = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)));
        r += r1 === 64 ? g(bm >> 16 & 255)
                : r2 === 64 ? g(bm >> 16 & 255, bm >> 8 & 255)
                : g(bm >> 16 & 255, bm >> 8 & 255, bm & 255);
    }
    return r;
};
```

you can kind of tell that it has something to do with base64, especially when given all valid characters in base64 encoded strings and forcing padding (`==`) based on the length of the input.

effectively, its just base64 decoding:

```js
const g = String.fromCharCode;
const o = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";
const e = function(s) {
    s += "==".slice(2 - (s.length & 3));
    var bm, r = "", r1, r2, i = 0;
    for (; i < s.length;) {
        bm = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 18 | o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)) << 12
                | (r1 = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++))) << 6 | (r2 = o.indexOf(s.charAt(i++)));
        r += r1 === 64 ? g(bm >> 16 & 255)
                : r2 === 64 ? g(bm >> 16 & 255, bm >> 8 & 255)
                : g(bm >> 16 & 255, bm >> 8 & 255, bm & 255);
    }
    return r;
};

const input = 'some input';
const base64 = window.btoa(input); // Buffer.from(input).toString('base64');

console.log(e(input))
console.log(base64)
console.log(e(base64))
```

It doesnt create an interval, but a single timeout of 400ms. Probably to "ensure" all of the dom is loaded. I suggest you'd skip this implementation and write your own based on the requirements of your application.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the `OBQXEnQ` variable, which is creating a "secret" including the length, which is presumably checked on the server. That seems to be the most obfuscated part of the code.

Comment: Yea that really the part that that's hard for me to understand

Comment: This is a good analysis of the function `e`, but this function is never called, so it serves no purpose.